# How to access the value from the controller to Directive in angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

I got the values in the Controller. I want that values to get access inside the diective. Is it possible..?

```
$scope.gridheader = [
{ headerName: "ID", field: "ID", seqNo: 0,checkboxSelection: true },
{ headerName: "Patient Name", field: "PatientName", seqNo: 1 },
{ headerName: "Gender", field: "Gender", seqNo: 3 },
{ headerName: "Age", field: "Age", seqNo: 2 },
{ headerName: "Phone Number", field: "mobileNumber", seqNo: 4 }
    ];

$scope.rowData = [
                     { ID: "09-14-002880", PatientName: "PRAVEEN KUMAR", Gender: "Male", Age: "20", mobileNumber: 9879878971, patientId: "test" },
                     { ID: "09-13-000188", PatientName: "VAR", Gender: "Male", Age: "20", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "ZXC12" },
                     { ID: "09-05-019825", PatientName: "KARMA", Gender: "Male", Age: "29", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "ZA2545635" },
                     { ID: "09-04-010524", PatientName: "FRANKLIN ANTHONY", Gender: "Male", Age: "20", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "Z7552396" },
                     { ID: "09-08-009303", PatientName: "DARYOUSH", Gender: "Male", Age: "29", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "Z2548467" },
                     { ID: "09-12-031048", PatientName: "SMITA", Gender: "Female", Age: "20", mobileNumber: 9880222187, patientId: "Z2296538" },
                     { ID: "09-11-026001", PatientName: "ADITYA DILIP", Gender: "Male", Age: "29", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "Z2277913" }
    ];

$scope.filterData = $scope.rowData;
    $scope.searchName = function() {
        $scope.searchData = $scope.quickregistration.SearchPatientId;
        if($scope.filterData != undefined ){
            $scope.rowData = $filter('filter')($scope.filterData, $scope.searchData);
        for(var key in $scope.rowData) {
                $scope.value = $scope.rowData[key];
            }       // here i got the values.. this value should be get access inside the directive
```

Comment: in you view(HTML), you can pass the desired value as element attribute, and recieve the same in directive

Comment: I have did the same , but not getting the values in directive.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example only containing the most important parts of code? I.e. controller, directive and usage in html.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to research. Did you look anywhere else for an answer?

Here is a short example of data binding between the directive and the html where you are using the directive.

data-binding with **=** and text binding with **@**, CamelCase in the directive is replaced by html-style hyphens (attributeName -> attribute-name)

If you know exactly what controllers you are using with this directive, you can access the parent scope with $parent (e.g. **$parent.someFunction()**).

In the HTML

```
<my-input-field model="modelValue" attribute-name="{{attributeName}}"></my-input-field>
```

In the directive:

```
scope: {
    model: '=model'
    attributeName: '@attributeName'
}
```

Read this: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/

Answer (score 0):

Use `@` Local Scope Property or `=` Local scope property (for two way binding) in your directive

ex:

```
return{

scope:{
   gridheader :'=',
   rowdata :'='
  }
};
```

and then pass these values as attributes in your directive

```
<my-directive gridheader="gridHeader" rowdata="rowData"></my-directive>
```

Here is a helpful example on **[custom directives](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope)**

Comment: Yes i have used the same in local scope property and also in directive but still the value is missng...

Comment: Please add your complete code (at least the major parts as suggested by @lisa p.)